# Reusing a View Controller with both push and modal segues

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have a View Controller that I want to re-use.  I want to use it with a **push** segue when *editing* some data and I want to present it **modally** when *adding* new data.
I do need a bar in the top with a Cancel and a Save button when presenting it modally.  I only need the Save button in the other case.

Obviously, the bar (and buttons) are only shown when I use a push segue.

Is there a way to re-use this View Controller and be able to use both a push and a modal segue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as Mital says but if you dont want to add a Bool try this:

```
if(self.presentingViewController != nil)
{
    //VC is presented modally
}

else
{
   //VC is pushed
}
```

It works as a charm for me.

Comment: Where would I put this code so that it runs when the segue pushes the new view controller? would it be in initWithCoder or something like that?

Comment: You can do it viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different Scenario, one you want to push and on the other hand you want to access it using segue, So, you can use flags for this. You can set a flag, and as per flag value you can set buttons and also push and segues as your flag's value.

in .h file:

```
BOOL flagForVc; // by default its 0
```

you can check by using this flag and display as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just embed your destinationController in a different navigationController say, newNavigation apart from the original navigationController. When you push using:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:YES];
```

it will show the top bar. Keep all your buttons etc on this navigation bar. 
When you want it to be modal just use:

```
[self presentViewController:newNavigation animated:YES]
```

and configure your barbutton items as you need them depending on the case.

You can just check whether it was a modal or push segue by checking

```
if ([[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:self]) {
    //modal related code
} else {
    // push related code
}
```